# How can i achieve this ? (reporting with codeigniter + MySql)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Good day. I'm trying to create a reporting with PHP + MySQL + HTML . Please check my script

```
 $data['bantu1'] = $this->db->query("select *from matapelajaran order by TipeMapel,Mapel asc")->result();
 $data['siswa']  = $this->db->query("select nik,namasiswa from mastersiswa order by namasiswa asc")->result();
        foreach($data['siswa'] as $sw) {
            $data['nilai'][$sw->nik][]  = $this->db->query("select * from rekapnilai where nik = '".$sw->nik."' ")->result();
        }
```

each of that will return this

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20170114005517
                [mapel] => BAHASA INDONESIA
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20170130031657
                [mapel] => Bahasa Inggris
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20161211124354
                [mapel] => MATEMATIKA
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20161205021910
                [mapel] => Pendidikan Agama dan Budi Pekerti
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20161206085653
                [mapel] => PKN
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20161211124453
                [mapel] => BAHASA ARAB MELAYU
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [KodeMapel] => MPL20161206085544
                    [mapel] => Kertakes
                )

        )
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['siswa']); die();
        Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nik] => NIK003
            [namasiswa] => Adi Suryono
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nik] => NIK002
            [namasiswa] => Anita Sari
        )

)

    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['nilai']); die();
    Array
    (
        [NIK003] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Idrekap] => 151
                                [nik] => NIK003
                                [nph] => 18
                                [npts] => 1
                                [npas] => 9
                                [IdPenilaian] => 15
                                [matapelajaran] => MPL20170114005517
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Idrekap] => 201
                                [nik] => NIK003
                                [nph] => 16
                                [npts] => 8
                                [npas] => 8
                                [IdPenilaian] => 17
                                [matapelajaran] => MPL20161211124354
                            )

                    )

            )

        [NIK002] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Idrekap] => 152
                                [nik] => NIK002
                                [nph] => 0
                                [npts] => 0
                                [npas] => 0
                                [IdPenilaian] => 15
                                [matapelajaran] => MPL20170114005517
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Idrekap] => 202
                                [nik] => NIK002
                                [nph] => 0
                                [npts] => 0
                                [npas] => 0
                                [IdPenilaian] => 17
                                [matapelajaran] => MPL20161211124354
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

so i already create a html table with this format.

[image]

and the table source

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rekap Nilai</title>
  <link href="<?=base_url();?>assets_admin2/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets_admin2/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets_admin2/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" class="table text-center table-bordered" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="4" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">No</td>
      <td width="4" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">Nama Siswa</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Spritual KI-1</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Spritual KI-1</td>
      <?php foreach($bantu1 as $pela) {?>
      <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle"><?=$pela->mapel;?></td>
      <?php } ?>
      <td width="6" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">Jumlah Nilai</td>
      <td width="6" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">Rangking</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="26" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom">C</td>
      <td width="39" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom">P</td>
      <td width="26" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom">C</td>
      <td width="33" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom">P</td>
        <?php foreach($bantu1 as $pela) {?>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Pengetahuan</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Keterampilan</td>
       <?php } ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <?php foreach($bantu1 as $pela) {?>
      <td width="10" align="center" valign="middle">C</td>
      <td width="6" align="center" valign="middle">P</td>
      <td width="6" align="center" valign="middle">C</td>
      <td width="6" align="center" valign="middle">P</td>
       <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php 


      $y=0; foreach($siswa as $rslt){ $y++;?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$y;?></td>
        <td><?=$rslt->namasiswa;?></td>
        <?php for($a=0;$a<2;$a++){ ?>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php foreach($bantu1 as $pela) {?> 
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <?php } ?>
        <td></td>
      <td></td>


    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Please check my first and the second query result(s). The connected condition is in here

```
[KodeMapel] =  [matapelajaran]
```

so, my desired result is like this

[image]

where the number coming from

> ([nph] +  [npts] + [npas]) / 4

Comment: Maybe I missed the question - what exactly is the problem you are having / what are you wanting to find out?

Comment: i want to create a reporting and i want it looks like the last picture i insert from my question. ah, i wish i can english well.